# unused result error, if condition c

Tags: c

I hope this is not a banal question but I just can't find the problem in my code. I keep getting the error message *"expression result unused"* and *"relational comparison result unused"* when trying to compile my code.
The problem is with the following function:

```
bool is_inside(double x, double y){

   if(sqrt(pow((x-0,5),2)+pow((y-0,5),2))<0,5){
       return true;
   }
   return false;    
}
```

which gets called in this function:

```
   void estimate_func(unsigned long nsteps, unsigned long nstep_print){

      unsigned long i;
      unsigned long in_circle=0;
      double x,y;
      double curr_pi,curr_s;

      for(i=0;i<nsteps;i++){

         x=drand48();
         y=drand48();

         if(is_inside(x,y)){      // call!!!
             in_circle++;
         }

         if(!(i%(nstep_print+1))){    

            curr_pi=(double) 4*(in_circle/(i+1));
            curr_s=4*(sqrt((curr_pi/4)*(1-curr_pi/4)/(double)(i+1)));

            printf("\t%lu\t%.6lf\t%.6lf\t%.6lf\n", i+1, curr_pi ,  
                                                   curr_pi-M_PI, curr_s);
         }       
       }
    }
```

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `xxx<0,5` become `5` ==> `true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, essentially, that C source code is not locale-aware. Clearly, in your locale, the comma is used as the decimal separator, so you write ½ as 0,5. C doesn't do it that way. It always uses the period as the decimal separator, so ½ is always 0.5.

The comma does something different in C. It's actually a distinct operator known as the *comma operator*. It evaluates both its operands, discards the result of the first, and returns the result of the second. So, taking into account the operator precedence, what you currently have is seen by the compiler as:

```
if((sqrt(pow(((x-0),5),2)+pow(((y-0),5),2))<0),5){
```

which, evaulating the inner comma operators, gives:

```
if((sqrt(pow(5,2)+pow(5,2))<0),5){
```

and evaluating the outer comma operator reduces to:

```
if(5){
```

which the compiler can tell is trivially `true`, and is therefore warning you about it. The `return false` block will never be reached.

The correct way to write the code would be:

```
bool is_inside(double x, double y){

   return (sqrt(pow((x - 0.5), 2) + pow((y - 0.5), 2)) < 0.5);
}
```

Notice that I have also elided the pointless `if` statement. This does exactly the same thing, and is easier to read. A comparison always returns either `1` (`true`) or `0` (`false`) in C, so its result can be used directly as a Boolean.

I've also added spaces, because *let that code breathe*!

Comment: Mhmm. Thanks, @alk. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation though and for the alternative code, I adopted it :)

Answer (score 2):

What maybe you want to do is this:

```
bool is_inside(double x, double y){

   if(sqrt(pow((x-0.5),2)+pow((y-0.5),2))<0.5){
       return true;
   }
   return false;    
}
```

Change the `,` to `.` if you want to represent floating point numbers (real numbers)

Comment: Thank you so much! so indeed this was really quite a stupid question, sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

Just refactoring your code a little bit:

```
bool is_inside(double x, double y){
 return sqrt(pow((x-0.5),2) + pow((y-0.5),2)) < 0.5); // changing , to .
}


void estimate_func(unsigned long nsteps, unsigned long nstep_print){
      unsigned long i, in_circle=0;
      double x, y, curr_pi, curr_s;

      for(i = 0; i < nsteps; i++){
         x = drand48();
         y = drand48();

         if(is_inside(x,y)) in_circle++;

         if(!(i % (nstep_print + 1))){    
            curr_pi = (double) 4 * (in_circle / (i + 1));
            curr_s =  4 * (sqrt((curr_pi / 4) * (1 - curr_pi / 4) / (double)(i + 1)));
            printf("\t%lu\t%.6lf\t%.6lf\t%.6lf\n", i + 1, curr_pi ,  
                                                   curr_pi - M_PI, curr_s);
         }       
       }
    }
```

Always try as much as possible to reduce the number of lines in your code. Beautiful code is short and concise. Check out these exercises http://divostar.com/learn-c